# Load data saved in form on a new form

Tags: forms, save, load, orbeon

I need to use Orbeon Forms to create a form to capture the price from a number of things. I create a form, connect it with database (MySQL), deploy the form, complete the form, and it saves the data correctly in database.

Then my question is: if I complete `form_1` and save the data in the database, and later enter to the empty `form_1`:

1. Is it possible to load the data entered previously or from the last form completion for `form_1`?
2. Is it necessary to have button or any control to take an action?

Answer (score 0):

When you load a page to fill a new form, notice how the URL ends with `/new`. When you are on that page, and save, notice how the URL changes to `/edit/123` (where `123` is a long unique identifier). You can come back to edit the data by loading again this URL.

In practice, this is often done by going to the `/summary` page for the form, and clicking on the relevant form data you want to edit.

Comment: thanks  It's clear to me, but i have a new question:
 if i save a data in `form_1` and later i need save a new data in `form_2`, but in this last form (form_2) i need pre loaded the data entered before in `form_1`,
 I think use the data from /edit/123 to load in the form/new/ is necessary use parameter example: `orbeon:8080/form/new/?123` . ¿this it's correct? ¿what it's you recommend? ¿exists any example for this?

Comment: I am not sure to follow: are `form_1` and `form_2` different forms you created in Form Builder? If that is the case, then Orbeon Forms doesn't know, out-of-the-box, how to take data entered by users in one form to pre-populate another form. But is this what you're asking about?